# How to clean yellow teeth

Tags: cleaning, home, food, personal-care, water

There is fluoride in the water that I use on the daily basis, and my teeth are having yellow shade. Is there any way to clean them?

Comment: It's unlikely the discoloration was caused by fluoride. Fluoride can only do this in young children. http://health.howstuffworks.com/wellness/oral-care/products/fluoride-make-teeth-yellow.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and searched some videos from youtube telling me to use baking soda with lemon juice for a week(BUT NOT MORE!!).

However all suggestions are not healthy, so be carefull and if possible speak to your dentist.

I know having white teeths is good and look nice but having a yellowish color does not mean that your teeths are not healthy.

Here is a reference from colgate which will also telling the same risk I am meaning.

> Baking soda is a common household product that has many uses around
>   the home, from eliminating smells to cleaning carpets. Now, baking
>   soda can be found in many toothpastes and teeth-whitening products.
>   Using it to remove stains from teeth is common practice.  It does an
>   excellent job at removing surface stains, but you should proceed with
>   caution to prevent damage to your enamel.
>   [Read more by Colgate.](http://www.colgate.com/en/us/oc/oral-health/cosmetic-dentistry/teeth-whitening/article/does-baking-soda-whiten-teeth-0113)

Comment: Regarding that YouTube video: lemon juice is very acidic (obviously).  A friend of mine used to eat lemons when he was a kid, and his dentist told him it ruined his enamel.  He had to have his teeth capped. So that one-week limit is very important!

Comment: @BrettFromLA I agree on that.I am always saying healthy teeth is much much better than a whitey teeth whit mouth smell.

I will also suggest to clean  your mouth with salt water once a week for 2 minutes to keep your mouth clean and healthy;but brush your teeths min 2 times per day with SOFT teethbrush. If possible also use teeth rope.

Answer (score 5):

Below is the cool trick which you can try if you want white teeth:
[image: banana peel]

**What do you need?** A banana peel, a toothbrush and toothpaste.

**What to do?** Rub the fleshy side of the peel to your teeth. Try to keep gums and lips away from paste for ten minutes. After the time is up, take a dry toothbrush use it to brush the banana paste into your teeth.

**Why banana peel?**  There are minerals in the banana peel like potassium, magnesium and manganese which are absorbed by the teeth, making them whiter.

**Here is WikiHow link:** http://www.wikihow.com/Whiten-Your-Teeth-with-Banana-Peel

Comment: I didn't see tooth whitening as a use for bananas in this link, could you add another one?

Comment: the given link is the url of the image of the banana.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know and also thank you for adding a link with the reference.

Comment: I hope I solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to consistent hygiene, oil pulling with coconut oil appears to have a natural whitening effect. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDvrQNWIsk4

Answer (score 1):

[Fluorosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_fluorosis) is extremely common but most often mostly harmless.
To 'clean' this is quite difficult.

However: Acids are always bad for your teeth. No matter how long they come into contact with your enamel. Some of the damage may be undone by your saliva, but it is better to avoid acids as much as possible. this includes any juices and fruit. Before the acids strip away the fluorosis to satisfactory levels you will have ruined your teeth.

Cleaning with baking soda is a much better option, in agreement with @melic. On the condition that you do not use it immediately, in its crystal form. That would be another nasty abrasive damaging your teeth while cleaning them. The link to a commercial site isn't clear enough on this. If you wait with the brushing until after your saliva or water has *completely* dissolved the crystals it is actually quite good a home remedy. Making the environment in your mouth both more basic (neutralising the acids) while simultaneously 'lifting' some of the plaque, making your brush and toothpaste more effective.

Try this demonstration at home: brew two cups of strong black tea, let it sit for a few hours, maybe sip on it from time to time, and watch how it stains the porcelain. Now try to wash both cups. One with your regular soap, one after soaking the innards of the cup for half an hour with a mixture of a spoonful of baking soda and water, only then washing it. The soaked cup is much more easily cleaned.

More severe cases of dental discolouration should be treated with a couple of visits to a dentist or other qualified personnel. Scaling, polishing and bleaching is better left to the professionals.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a life hack, but just general good advice (from someone that ate lotsa lemons as a kid).

Here's the thing. Enamel is white. Dentine, the part under the enamel is yellow. Yellow teeth are generally caused by two things. 1) there are stains on the surface of the enamel. 2) the enamel has worn away (to some extent) and the yellow dentine is now showing through.

for 1) an oral hygienist should be able to remove tarter and other types of stains
for 2) a dentist can bleach the dentine so that your teeth appear whiter

Some additional notes;

- excessive brushing with abrasive and corrosive compounds can in fact make your teeth appear more yellow as the enamel is worn away and the dentine exposed
- taking care of your teeth is a life long commitment. You should have your teeth cleaned professionally at least once a year by an oral hygienist.

Hope this helps.

Above all else, floss every day and brush twice a day, and look after every single tooth. Only ever have a tooth removed as the last possible resort.